# perl5 substitution with blank elements

Tags: perl, scripting

I have this file with Reg numbers that have a space between the numbers and the letter, 1234567 A.  I want to have 1234567A

```
$line =~ s/^(\w+),(\w+),(\d+),(\d+)(\s+)(\w)/\1,\2,\3,\4\6/;
```

This will change

```
surname, middle_name, id, Reg_no
Tommy,t,1,1234567 A
```

into

```
Tommy,t,1,1234567A
```

as I want.

But if I have

```
Tommy,,1,1234567 A
```

It will not change remaining 1234567 A.  Seems it's the blank (null?) contents in the second cell is causing the problem.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best bet could be using a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) parser, like `Text::CSV_XS` module, but as a quick & dirty solution, you can use some switches to split the line in commas, get the third field, remove first space, and print again:

```
perl -F, -lanE '$. > 1 and $F[3] =~ s/\s+//; do { $" = q|,|; say "@F" } ' infile
```

It yields:

```
surname, middle_name, id, Reg_no
Tommy,t,1,1234567A
Tommy,,1,1234567A
```